# What is the correct way to guess either user is registered or admin in window forms?

Tags: c#, sql

I developed an windows application now i want to provide a security.

My requirement is to provide few functionalities to the user and some full
  access to the admin.

When some one entered username and password i stored role as user in database
  by default.

But how to give access to the admin if he logged.

I know if i provide one drop down while adding details to the sql database. In
  dropdown will give options either user or admin.

I don't want this type. I have only 2 fields username and password and i want
  to give an option to the admin if he logged.

Note: I don't want to go database and enter the admin details there.

Is there any option while login we will change the option as admin?

Thanks Any Suggestions.

Comment: If you don't store some kind of role or flag to designate a user as admin when you create the user - how do you expect to recognize them as an admin? You've gotta set a flag or add a role in your database.

Comment: Hello i already add a role column in my table by default i stored role as user but now i want to store role as admin how can i? In my insert statement while adding a record in my table i set role value to 0 means it is a user now i want to set role to 1 means it is a admin?now how can i set?and how to pass this 1 value to my insert statement?because insert stored procedure @role=0 i added by default now i want to pass 1 after login i don't want before login is it possible?Thanks